# Why does Qt's version of libstdc++-6.dll work, but not MinGW?

Tags: c, windows, qt, netbeans, mingw

I'm very new to C, Netbeans, Qt, and any linking more complicated than `import antigravity`. I'm getting confused trying to setup Netbeans for Qt. I'm on Windows 7.

I installed MinGW, and then separately installed the Qt SDK. When I installed the latter, I opted out of MinGW, since I already had that. I think I have all the paths set up correctly in Netbeans - I can build a basic Qt app.

When I try to run the app, I get this error:

[image]*

I have two copies of that DLL on my PATH: the one that came with MinGW, and the one that came with Qt. When I copy paste the MinGW one into the app folder and run the app, I get the above error. When I copy paste the Qt one into the folder, no errors.

So there's a difference between the Qt DLL and the MinGW one. This is very unsetlling to me. What is this DLL, why is it in my Qt install if I chose not to include MinGW, and why is it different from the one in my MinGW install? Should I just rip MinGW and Qt out of my system and reinstall a fresh Qt SDK with the included MinGW? I want to do other kinds of C programming than just Qt, so it felt "right" to me to have separate MinGW install.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening:

It's finding the DLL but cannot find the requested object within that DLL. The mingw library probably has different content than the stdlib library. You have a mismatch between different sets of code.

My suggestion:

Use the Mingw packaged with Qt. They've done the work validating it works with Qt. Why not take advantage of it?

When I did this last year I did have to search for the right version of make. It wasn't provided at the time.